# Android floating window element

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

So I have a cordova/phonegap app that I am developing. I want to create a portion of the app so that it displays on top of the entire system UI, sort of like a menu. It will be a little button at the bottom of the screen that when clicked, it will preform some action. (sort of like facebook chat heads)

I was wondering if anyone would know how to code something like that for android 4.4.

It doesn't have to be compatable with cordova/phone gap, but I would like to somehow display a html event inside of whatever solution there is out there.

Thank you in advance!